# Remove temp folder in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I have a Symfony application and I want to delete a temp folder which is also created by Symfony

First Im creating the temp folder:

```
public function getTempDir()
{
    $dirName = dirname(__DIR__).'/var/temp';
    if (!file_exists($dirName)) {
        mkdir($dirName, 0777, true);
    }

    return $dirName;
}
```

and at the end I want to delete a specific folder in the directory with the whole content in it.
I tried different functions, but none of them is working. The folder still exists.
For example:

```
public function removeTempFolder($path)
{
    $this->_log("removeTempFolder: " . $path);
    if (is_dir($path)) {
        $objects = scandir($path);
        foreach ($objects as $object) {
            if ($object != "." && $object != "..") {
                if (filetype($path . "/" . $object) == "dir") {
                    unlink($path . "/" . $object);
                    $this->removeTempFolder($path . "/" . $object);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
(new Filesystem)->remove($path);
```

or

```
exec("rm -rf " . $pathToTempFile);
```

What is missing?

Comment: Your `removeTempFolder()` method doesn't seem to actually remove anything.

Comment: I missed the unlink, but it is still doesn't remove anything